# unexpected output from quantile function

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

For the following code, I expect to see each number (1-25) to appear 4 times under 4 different percentile values. However, at percentiles 28 and 56 the results are not as expected. The 28th percentile should be 7 and the 56th percentile should be 14.

```
> quantile(1:25, seq(0,1,0.01), type=1)
  0%   1%   2%   3%   4%   5%   6%   7%   8%   9%  10%  11%  12%  13%  14%  15%  16%  17%  18%  19%  20%  21%  22%  23%  24%  25%  26%  27%  28% 
   1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    5    5    5    5    6    6    6    6    7    7    7    8 
 29%  30%  31%  32%  33%  34%  35%  36%  37%  38%  39%  40%  41%  42%  43%  44%  45%  46%  47%  48%  49%  50%  51%  52%  53%  54%  55%  56%  57% 
   8    8    8    8    9    9    9    9   10   10   10   10   11   11   11   11   12   12   12   12   13   13   13   13   14   14   14   15   15 
 58%  59%  60%  61%  62%  63%  64%  65%  66%  67%  68%  69%  70%  71%  72%  73%  74%  75%  76%  77%  78%  79%  80%  81%  82%  83%  84%  85%  86% 
  15   15   15   16   16   16   16   17   17   17   17   18   18   18   18   19   19   19   19   20   20   20   20   21   21   21   21   22   22 
 87%  88%  89%  90%  91%  92%  93%  94%  95%  96%  97%  98%  99% 100% 
  22   22   23   23   23   23   24   24   24   24   25   25   25   25
```

If we use a different size vector, the same (and more) percentile values will not be correct.

Another example where the 7th, 14th, 28th, 55th and 56th percentile values are wrong:

```
> quantile(1:100, seq(0,1,0.01), type=1)
  0%   1%   2%   3%   4%   5%   6%   7%   8%   9%  10%  11%  12%  13%  14%  15%  16%  17%  18%  19%  20%  21%  22%  23%  24%  25%  26%  27%  28% 
   1    1    2    3    4    5    6    8    8    9   10   11   12   13   15   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   29 
 29%  30%  31%  32%  33%  34%  35%  36%  37%  38%  39%  40%  41%  42%  43%  44%  45%  46%  47%  48%  49%  50%  51%  52%  53%  54%  55%  56%  57% 
  29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   56   57   58 
 58%  59%  60%  61%  62%  63%  64%  65%  66%  67%  68%  69%  70%  71%  72%  73%  74%  75%  76%  77%  78%  79%  80%  81%  82%  83%  84%  85%  86% 
  58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86 
 87%  88%  89%  90%  91%  92%  93%  94%  95%  96%  97%  98%  99% 100% 
  87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100
```

What is the reason for this? Is this a bug?

Comment: This might be simpler to see `quantile(1:5, seq(0,1,0.05), type=1)`

Comment: Isn't 1 appearing 5 times in your first result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong in saying the answers are "not correct." Remember that this is based on the ECDF meaning it is an empirical result not a theoretical one, and the 9 different methods are just about what to do when the empirical results can't be used but you need to use some method to interpolate etc.  Using your first example if we take the integers from 1 to 25 and calculate a conventional cumulative distribution we ge

```
Values Freq Percent Cum. Percent  
 1      1    4       4           
 2      1    4       8           
 3      1    4       12          
 4      1    4       16          
 5      1    4       20          
 6      1    4       24          
 7      1    4       28          
 8      1    4       32          
 9      1    4       36          
 10     1    4       40          
 11     1    4       44          
 12     1    4       48          
 13     1    4       52          
 14     1    4       56          
 15     1    4       60          
 16     1    4       64          
 17     1    4       68          
 18     1    4       72          
 19     1    4       76          
 20     1    4       80          
 21     1    4       84          
 22     1    4       88          
 23     1    4       92          
 24     1    4       96          
 25     1    4       100
```

So each observed value represents 4 percent of your sample.  What do 28 and 56 have in common? They are both multiples of 4 and they are the only two places where they also represent the lower boundary of the "quantile range" for a value. So they get pushed up. I think Type 2 actually best illustrates this.

```
a<-quantile(y, seq(0,1,0.01), type=1)
b<-quantile(y, seq(0,1,0.01), type=2)
c<-quantile(y, seq(0,1,0.01), type=3)
quantiles<-data.frame(a,b,c)
quantiles[1:30,]

      a    b  c
0%    1  1.0  1
1%    1  1.0  1
2%    1  1.0  1
3%    1  1.0  1
4%    1  1.5  1
5%    2  2.0  1
6%    2  2.0  2
7%    2  2.0  2
8%    2  2.5  2
9%    3  3.0  2
10%   3  3.0  2
11%   3  3.0  3
12%   3  3.5  3
13%   4  4.0  3
14%   4  4.0  4
15%   4  4.0  4
16%   4  4.5  4
17%   5  5.0  4
18%   5  5.0  4
19%   5  5.0  5
20%   5  5.5  5
21%   6  6.0  5
22%   6  6.0  6
23%   6  6.0  6
24%   6  6.5  6
25%   7  7.0  6
26%   7  7.0  6
27%   7  7.0  7
28%   8  8.0  7
29%   8  8.0  7
30%   8  8.0  8
31%   8  8.0  8
32%   8  8.5  8
33%   9  9.0  8
```

Type 3 is out on a different planet with the odd/even thing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that these are the only places where they represent the lower boundary of the quantile range. Doesn't every percentile that is a multiple of 4 represent the lower boundary of a quantile range?

Comment: No sometimes they are in the middle or at the top.  Look at 4, 8 and 12 for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods for calculating quantiles which can give slightly different answers. You are using type 1. Types 3 or 4 give the answers that you are expecting.

See `?quantile` for the details.

`quantile(1:25, seq(0, 1, 0.01), type = 4)[29]
28%
  7`

Comment: They don't seem to give me the right answers. Type 3 gives the same as Type 1, and type 2 interpolates `quantile(1:5, seq(0,1,0.05), type = 3)`

Comment: What I am seeing is that type 3 and 4 are providing the same results for the first example. See this: quantile(1:25, seq(0,1,0.01), type=3)

Comment: Edited answer with output from my system. Perhaps it is platform-dependent.